# CLIPS: How can I allow users to input sentences as answers? Jasmine Flower Guess

Tags: artificial-intelligence, clips, expert-system

Im currently working on a CLIPS program that guesses the name of the jasmine flower based only on the flower color and season, but I don't know how to use sentences as possibles answers to be able to get answers like "spring to autumn"

Here's the code:

```
    (deftemplate jazmin 
    (slot nombre) 
    (slot color-flor
        (allowed-values blanca amarilla)) 
    (slot temporada
        (allowed-values primavera verano primavera-a-otoño verano-a-otoño invierno-a-primavera)) 
)

(defrule in-color-flor
    =>
    (printout t "Inserte el color de la flor: ")
    (assert (color-flor (read)))
)

(defrule in-temporada
    =>
    (printout t "Inserte en que temporada florece: ")
    (assert (temporada (read)))
)

(defrule buscar-jazmin
    (color-flor ?color)
    (temporada ?temporada)
    (jazmin (nombre ?nombre) (color-flor ?color-flor) (temporada ?temporada))
    =>
    (printout t "El nombre del jazmin descrito es: " ?nombre crlf)
)

(defrule jazmin-no-encontrado
    (color ?color-flor)
    (temporada ?temporada)
    (not (jazmin (nombre ?nombre) (color-flor ?color-flor) (temporada ?temporada)))
    =>
    (printout t "El jazmin descrito no se encuentra" crlf)
)

(deffacts jazmines
    (jazmin (nombre Jazmin-Blanco) (color-flor blanca) (temporada primavera-a-otono))
    (jazmin (nombre Jazmin-Chino) (color-flor blanca) (temporada primavera))
    (jazmin (nombre Jazmin-Silvestre) (color-flor amarilla) (temporada verano))
    (jazmin (nombre Jazmin-Azor) (color-flor amarilla) (temporada primavera))
    (jazmin (nombre Jazmin-Espanol) (color-flor blanca) (temporada verano-a-otono))
    (jazmin (nombre Jazmin-Amarillo) (color-flor amarilla) (temporada invierno-a-primavera))
)
```

Also I'm curious if there's a better way to optimize for options such as Spring to Autumn without having to put the whole sentences as one answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can write rules to expand either the user's answer or the values in the temporada slot to include seasons between two other seasons:

```
CLIPS> 
(deffacts seasons
   (season-order primavera verano otono invierno primavera))
CLIPS>    
(defrule expand-season-1
   ?f <- (seasons $?first ?s1 to ?s2)
   (season-order $? ?s1 ?s2 $?)
   =>
   (retract ?f)
   (assert (seasons ?first ?s1 ?s2)))
CLIPS>    
(defrule expand-season-2
   ?f <- (seasons $?first ?s1 to ?s3)
   (season-order $? ?s1 ?s2&~?s3 $?)
   =>
   (retract ?f)
   (assert (seasons ?first ?s1 ?s2 to ?s3)))
CLIPS> 
(defrule get-seasons
   =>
   (print "Seasons? ")
   (assert (seasons (explode$ (readline)))))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
Seasons? invierno to verano
CLIPS> (facts)
f-1     (season-order primavera verano otono invierno primavera)
f-4     (seasons invierno primavera verano)
For a total of 2 facts.
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
Seasons? otono primavera
CLIPS> (facts)
f-1     (season-order primavera verano otono invierno primavera)
f-2     (seasons otono primavera)
For a total of 2 facts.
CLIPS>
```